# Grappl extension on vscode

Tags: visualization, integration, vscode-extensions, jira-rest-api

Just wanted to share that I have put out a vscode extension on the marketplace, called [Grappl](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=grappl.grappl). It allows you to visualise your source code into a 3D city model. The bigger the building, the more complex the component… there’s more to it, but for now I’d be really grateful to hear what you think of it guys. Any thoughts will be immensely valuable please 
[Grappl](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Blaiski/Grappl/main/images/GrapplCover.png)
Thank you!

Mujtaba